# How to explode on the first number of string

Tags: php, explode

I have addresses I want to explode to get only the name of the street.

For example, I've got : "1 rue du general, 75000, Paris" and I need an array with the number and the street name 
array('1','rue du Général, 75000, Paris').

I thought to explode on first occurrence but sometimes, I've this : "Lot 12 rue du Général, 75000, Paris", or other time : "12 avenue du general, 75000, Paris".

So basically, I think it's easier to explode on the first number it find no?

Comment: So you want 2 elements every time?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<?php

 $address = "Lot 12 rue du Gal, 75000, Paris";
 $street = substr($address,0,strpos($address,","));
 echo $street . PHP_EOL;

 $elements = explode(" ",$street);
 $number = "";
 $street_name = "";
  foreach ($elements as $value) {
   if (is_numeric($value)) {
    $number = $value;
    $street_name = substr($street,strpos($street, $value) + strlen($value)+1);
   }
 }
 echo $number . PHP_EOL . $street_name . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

which results in the following output (tested for other 2 test cases, appears to work for those as well)

```
Lot 12 rue du Gal  <- street address
12                 <- street number  $number
rue du Gal         <- street name    $street_name
```

Comment: This won't help him, he stated that it's not guaranteed that a string starts with a number. In that case your solution will create two elements, one with the non-important prefix and one with the entire street plus number.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find the first occurence of a number in your string using Regex. This will give you a position in the string. If you extract the number from the string, you can store this in a temporally variable. Once you've done this, you need to take a `substr()` of the string, starting at the END of the digit, so you take the position of the number and add it's length, to get the start of the street name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you just want to get the street names. You should be able to achieve this with the following Regular Expression:

```
[0-9+]+[,\s]*([^,]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CqCj9hmjtqvYunqj)

Or, in PHP code with your examples:

```
$addresses = [
    '1 rue du general, 75000, Paris',
    'Lot 12 rue du Général, 75000, Paris',
    '12 avenue du general, 75000, Paris',
    '1, Place du Général, 7500, Paris',
];

$streets = array_map(function ($address) {
    if (preg_match('/[0-9+]+[,\s]*([^,]+)/', $address, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
}, $addresses);

print_r($streets);

// Output:
// 
// Array
// (
//     [0] => rue du general
//     [1] => rue du Général
//     [2] => avenue du general
//     [3] => Place du Général
// )
```

You could also put this in a helper function:

```
function extractStreet($address) {
    if (preg_match('/[0-9+]+[,\s]*([^,]+)/', $address, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    }

    return null;
}

$addresses = [
    '1 rue du general, 75000, Paris',
    'Lot 12 rue du Général, 75000, Paris',
    '12 avenue du general, 75000, Paris',
    '1, Place du Général, 7500, Paris',
];

foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    echo extractStreet($address) . PHP_EOL;
}

// Output:
//
// rue du general
// rue du Général
// avenue du general
// Place du Général
```